# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `data` of type `object` supplied to `Carousel`, expected `array`

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native, carousel, react-native-snap-carousel

I am using react-native-snap-carousel, It worked fine, It fetches data fine but i am getting 2 warnings in that app.

1. Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `data` of type `boolean` supplied to `Carousel`, expected `array`.
2. Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `dotsLength` is marked as required in `Pagination` but it's value is `Undefined`.

**1 brother from comments helped me and my problem is solved now, That's why i am removing code, Because that was my company's code, and i don't have permission to share code for long time after getting answered.
Thanks.**

Comment: Can you log value of `msgResponse`?

Comment: let me show you the data

Comment: I have updated the code with logs screenshots, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the first issue, I see that the msgResponse is inconsistent

```
 const msgResponse = responseMsg._embedded && responseMsg._embedded.items ? responseMsg._embedded.items : ''
```

array / string depending on the case

try:

```
 const msgResponse = responseMsg._embedded && responseMsg._embedded.items ? responseMsg._embedded.items : []
```